# Find two nodes and create relationship between them (neo4j in python)

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm trying to find two nodes in my database and then create a relationship between them. I'm using the neo4j python package. Current code looks like so:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
graphDB_Driver  = GraphDatabase.driver(...) 
db = graphDB_Driver.session()

db.run("MERGE (a:Person {name:'Homer'})")
db.run("MERGE (a:Person {name:'Marge'})")
```

This part works fine.

Now how do I retrieve the two nodes above and create a relationship between them?

```
db.run("MERGE (:Person {name:'Homer'})-[:married_to]->(:Person {name:'Marge'})")
```

This ends up creating two more nodes, and then connecting them. Is there some way to fetch the original two nodes in order to connect them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MATCH to the nodes first and then MERGE the relationship between them

```
MATCH (homer:Person {name:'Homer'}), (marge:Person {name:'Marge'})
MERGE (homer)-[:married_to]-(marge)
```

You'll want to have an index on :Person(name) so the initial lookups are fast.

We have a knowledge base article on [understanding how MERGE works](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/) that can help you get a better grasp on some of the more subtle points of the MERGE clause.

Comment: I see. I haven't gotten into the efficiency of all this yet, but since I'm creating the node a few lines above, I have the feeling that I shouldn't have to then search all the nodes to find it again in order to create the edge. In other words, can't I return some sort of pointer to the node upon creation, which I can then use for the edge creation?

Comment: It would be best if you just use a single Cypher query rather than one each for the merges and then a third for the relationship. Just do it all at once: `db.run("MERGE (a:Person {name:'Homer'}) MERGE (a:Person {name:'Marge'}) MERGE (homer)-[:married_to]-(marge)")` Once you create an index on :Person(name) then it will be an index lookup for each of the nodes later, when you need it.